# firmware-updater functionality

Tags: firmware

Ubuntu 23.10 has a firmware updater with the ability to [verify firmware] and [update checksums]. I'm not sure what these mean, but in pressing them, nothing seems to happen.

When I [update checksums] on an SD Card entry, I see "This will record the current cryptographic hashes as verified" (whatever that means) and again, nothing happens. Unless I maximise the screen and & then I see in the corner an unending "waiting for authentication".

Is this a known bug?  nothing seems to update.

Comment: How does this question differ from the one you posted over an hour ago?

Comment: The first question is a matter of functionality of the options. This one is regarding the software being stuck in "waiting for authentication"